# Vimeo embedded video cannot be played in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, vimeo

Here is my config:
- Mac 10.9
- Firefox 28-29

My iframe containing the Vimeo video stays black and displays this error message:
< This video can't be played with your current setup. >
It works fine in all the other browsers.

[image]

```
Markup iframe:  
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/83913899?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=111" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="0" kwframeid="1"></iframe>
```

Link to page:
http://www.monakimprojects.com/projects/uniqlo-campaign#slide-02

PS : A friend told me it works fine for Firefox 29, Mac OS X 10.6.
So it looks like it is an OSX problem.

Comment: You should post your markup

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VIMEO support answered :

> You need to have flash installed to watch Vimeo videos in Firefox on
>   OS X because they don't support h.264 playback.

Ah hum yes ok I just reinstalled my Mac a few days ago thats why...
But could they make their message more precise no?

Instead of a silly joke and

> This video cannot be played with the current setup

I would have prefer

> This video needs flash player installed to be played

Agree VIMEO team?
Thx.

Comment: I've also come across this issue. That's very poor coming from Vimeo. I can't expect my website users to have flash installed. Tweeted about this: https://twitter.com/andyeo/status/471650967990325248

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet because of lack of reputation, but there's something I think is worth sharing.

Chrome and Firefox have disabled Flash across the board. Users would have to update or reinstall Flash. This makes it worse for the situation mentioned in this post. Not so much for Chrome since it plays without using Flash, but definitely a problem for Firefox on Mac, which users may not know an update is necessary to view the Vimeo video.

[Google and Mozilla pull the plug on Adobe Flash: Tech giants disable the program on browsers following 'critical' security flaw](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3160644/Google-Mozilla-pull-plug-Adobe-Flash-Tech-giants-disable-program-browsers-following-critical-security-flaw.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14 and the solution that worked for me was to install Adobe Flash!